# Ajax: How to pass variable one function to another jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to use variable as selector but its limited to one function, how to pass that variable value to other functions as well. I'm new to ajax, please help me to solve this issue.

I tried local storage but that also didn't work.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<td class="info-group jname">
    <p class="pro-info-right text-per jname"><?php echo $jsdata['js_fname']; ?></p>
    <div class="edit jname" style="display:none">
        <input class="editbox jname" name="js_fname_edit" value="">
    </div>
    <?php if($this->user_valid == TRUE) {  ?>
    <a href="#"><span title="Edit"  class="edit-icon jname ctrl glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a href="#"><span title="Delete" class="del-icon ctrl glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
    <?php } ?>
</td>

<td class="info-group jaddr">
    <p class="pro-info-right text-per jaddr"><?php echo $jsdata['js_address']; ?></p>
    <div class="edit jaddr" style="display:none">
        <input class="editbox jaddr" name="js_fname_edit" value="">
    </div>
    <?php if($this->user_valid == TRUE) {  ?>
    <a href="#"><span title="Edit" class="edit-icon jaddr glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a href="#"><span title="Delete" class="jaddr del-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slctd;
    $('.info-group').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        slctd = ($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
        $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').hide();
        $('.'+ slctd +' .ctrl').hide();
        var data = $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').html();
        $('.'+ slctd +' .edit').show();
        $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').val(data);
        $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').focus();//comming up to here
    });
    $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').mouseup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//not comming here
        return false;
    });
    $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').change(function(e) {
        alert(slctd);//not comming here
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.'+ slctd +' .edit').hide();
        var js_address = $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').val();
        var dataString = 'js_address='+ js_address;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/Jobseeker/edit_personal' ?>"+'_'+ slctd +'',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').html(js_address);
                $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').show();
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//not comming here
        $('.'+ slctd +' .edit').hide();
        $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').show();
        $('.'+ slctd +' .ctrl').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Still the same problem, `slctd` is `undefined` when you're binding events

Comment: @Tushar yeah its says undefined, please give me any possible solution for this

Comment: The issue is you are defining the event handles based on a variable that hasn't been set yet.  That is why you are getting the undefined

Comment: You really don't need `slctd` variable at all, you just need `$(this)` inside the event handler

Comment: @SahanPerera Check the code http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tng51soj/ clean :)

Comment: @Tushar your answer is exactly what I was looking for, put that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the same code written in other style. This is more efficient and better code.

Basically `slctd` is nothing but `.info-group` element and you can use context selector to select the elements inside the clicked `td` by passing the selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // When clicked on the element having class info-group
    $('.info-group').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this); // Cache the context for performance

        $this.find('.text-per, .ctrl').hide(); // Hide the elements inside the clicked td matching the classes
        var data = $('.text-per', this).html(); // This is context selector, passing this here will search for .text-per element inside the this i.e. td element
        $('.edit', this).show();
        $('.editbox', this).val(data).focus(); // You can chain methods here
    }).on('mouseup', '.editbox', function (e) {
        // when mouseup of .editbox inside the .info-group
        return false; // preventDefault is not needed when using return false
    }).on('change', '.editbox', function (e) {
        var parentTd = $(this).closest('.info-group'); // Get the parent <td> object, so that this can be used as context for selecting the elements inside it

        $('.edit', parentTd).hide(); // Hide .edit element inside the td
        var value = $('.editbox', parentTd).val();
        var dataString = $('.editbox', parentTd).attr('name') + '=' + value; // Create data-string as Name=Value format

        // Send AJAX request using appropriate data
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/Jobseeker/edit_personal' ?>" + '_' + parentTd + '',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('.text-per', parentTd).html(value).show(); // Update html after successful completion of ajax
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.edit').hide();
        $('.text-per').show();
        $('.ctrl').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If `slctd` is  not determined until `$('.info-group').click`, then you must put all your code that depends on `slctd` inside the click function.

```
$('.info-group').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // this is the ONLY place that slctd is being defined at.
    slctd = ($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);

    $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').hide();
    $('.'+ slctd +' .ctrl').hide();
    var data = $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').html();
    $('.'+ slctd +' .edit').show();
    $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').val(data);
    $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').focus();//comming up to here

    // PUT ALL OTHER CODE THAT USES slctd HERE
});
```

Since other users have asked. Please be careful about this technique because it will only bind events to the slctd element every time you click on .info-group.

You may want to look at a different technique or perhaps unbind the previous events:

```
var current_slctd;

$('.info-group').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // code below will be about binding to new slctd

    // this is the ONLY place that slctd is being defined at.
    var slctd = ($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);

    if (current_slctd == slctd) {
       // return since this value of slctd has already been done
       return;
    } else {
       // UNBIND events on current_slctd
    }

    // start over and bind new events
    current_slctd = slctd;

    $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').hide();
    $('.'+ slctd +' .ctrl').hide();
    var data = $('.'+ slctd +' .text-per').html();
    $('.'+ slctd +' .edit').show();
    $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').val(data);
    $('.'+ slctd +' .editbox').focus();//comming up to here

    // PUT ALL OTHER CODE THAT USES slctd HERE
});
```

Comment: You also should clean up the event handlers you create in here or you will end up defining multiple event handlers on the same object

Comment: _// PUT ALL OTHER CODE THAT USES slctd HERE_ so the event will be bound again and again when clicked

Comment: @Tushar it is up to OP to prevent that or find a different way to get the value for `slctd`

Comment: this method pretty seems to be working, but there was one issue, first I edited `jaddr` then I edited  `jname` then I loss the data of `jname`

Comment: @SahanPerera No, this will bring issues, try to click the `.info-group` button multiple times and then mouseover on other elements on which event is bound

Comment: @HieuLe you might want to state that in your answer then. If the OP is just starting to learn jquery and Ajax you can expect them to know all of the in workings of events

Comment: No its working I guess, I need to change some codes `js_address` part with if condition

Comment: @SahanPerera -Tushar is correct you may not see it with just one click but if you click on the object over and over again you will start to see slow downs and even issues with the different event handlers fighting to do the same thing

Comment: I am still pretty new here @Aaron, but should people answering questions have to be responsible for future problems for other people's work instead of just answering the current question and let OP figure it out himself/herself. Don't we want people to try to figure out it themselves?

Comment: Still I'm trying to get error, but nothing and its working perfectly though

Comment: @SahanPerera is your value of slctd changing everytime you click on a diff .info-group?

Comment: @HieuLe yeah its changing, I don't understand, why people down-voted the question

Comment: I would suggest taking one problem at a time, if an issue arises, then fix it. If everything looks ok for you right now then you can move on. :)

Comment: @HieuLe I think in this case that type of information is necessary as the OP is new to the language. And while there are always many answers to the types of questions and the level of detail in the answers can vary a good answer would try to take into account statements that the OP might have make like they are "new" and make sure if you are not going to provide a complete solution that follows the best practice of the language you should IMO it should be noted as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @HieuLe I do agree that people need to go off and research the answers provided so they fully understand what is the answer is doing so they can learn and grow.